# receive serialize data in php sent via ajax and loop through it

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, serialization, deserialization

I am sending a form data via ajax call to a php script. I am serializing the data in ajax and on the php script I want to loop through that data to extract the values. 
This is my ajax call

```
$("#submitAttendance").click(function(){
            var data = $('form#attendanceForm').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                url: 'save-attendance.php',
                method: 'post',
                data: {formData: data},
                success: function(data){
                    console.log(data);
                    alert(data);
                }
        });
        });
```

and in the `attendance.php` I am doing

```
print_r(($_POST['formData']));//prints the entire serialize data
```

when I do this

```
parse_str($_POST['formData'], $searcharray);

print_r(($searcharray));//prints only last user and all radio buttons
```

I want to extract values so I can save it in db.
This is my form

```
<form action="" id="attendanceForm">
            <?php
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo($row['id']);?>">
                        <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $row['fullname'];?>" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>" readonly</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="class" value="<?php echo $row['class'];?>" readonly</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="present" name="<?php echo($row['id']); ?>" checked></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="absent" name="<?php echo($row['id']); ?>"></td>
                    </tr>


                <?php }
            }
            ?>
                <input id="submitAttendance" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit Attendance" name="submitAttendance">
            </form>
```

Comment: You dont need to do ' data: {formData: data}' just do data: data. You can than do a normal ' $_POST['name']' to retrieve your posted values.

Comment: Ye you are passing an array of data so you need to rename than as an array

Comment: i have to do some kind of loop since values are repeated. @Franco

Comment: You need now to loop trough the $_POST array to get your values in the php file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to @Jan answer I did following to get the complete data and loop through it

parse the incoming data

```
parse_str($_POST['formData'], $searcharray);
```

then loop through the array

```
for ($i = 0 ; $i <= sizeof($searcharray) ; $i++){
            $name = $searcharray['name'][$i];
            $email=   $searcharray['email'][$i];
            $class =  $searcharray['class'][$i];
            $present=  ($searcharray['present'][$i]);
    }
```

and my form code is

```
<form action="" id="attendanceForm">
            <?php
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                $i=0;
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

                    ?>
                    <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo($row['id']);?>">
                        <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $row['fullname'];?>" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>" readonly</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="class[]" value="<?php echo $row['class'];?>" readonly</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="present" name="present[<?php echo $i; ?>]" checked></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="absent" name="present[<?php echo $i; ?>]"></td>
                    </tr>


                <?php $i++;
                }
            }
            ?>
                <input id="submitAttendance" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit Attendance" name="submitAttendance">
            </form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to rename your items to be able to post arrays (that is call them "whatever" + "[]" and loop over them in PHP), e.g.:

**HTML:**

```
<form action="" id="attendanceForm">
            <?php
            if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
                while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){ ?>
                    <tr>
                        <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo($row['id']);?>">
                        <td><input type="text" name="name[]" value="<?php echo $row['fullname'];?>" readonly></td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="email[]" value="<?php echo $row['email'];?>" readonly</td>
                        <td><input type="text" name="class[]" value="<?php echo $row['class'];?>" readonly</td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="present" name="<?php echo($row['id']); ?>" checked></td>
                        <td><input type="radio" value="absent" name="<?php echo($row['id']); ?>"></td>
                    </tr>


                <?php }
            }
            ?>
                <input id="submitAttendance" type="button" class="btn btn-success" value="Submit Attendance" name="submitAttendance">
            </form>
```

**Later in PHP:**

```
foreach ($_POST["formData"]["name"] as $name)
    echo "Wow, $name is a really pretty name!";
```

Additionally, I am not sure what `present` and `absent` are meant to do and why they should have the same name (an id). You are already posting the id as an hidden field, why should it be done twice? One overrides the other one (as the names have to be unique).

Comment: i want to have a diff id associated with each user

Comment: ok that's great, it returned me the complete response now but will you like to tell why we have to put `[]` in front of name

Comment: As said, a name has to be unique, so you will need to send an array instead. Thus, it comes down to name[0], name[1] and so on which is unique as well.

Comment: and how I will loop through the results? simple foreach loop is not working

Comment: @Adamnick: It will, see my updated answer and the PHP part at the end.

Comment: this is what i got 
`Undefined index: name in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\attendance\save-attendance.php</b> on line <b>18</b><br />`

Comment: this is what it returned so values are there for sure

Comment: @Adamnick: my mistake, see the updated answer (including formdata).